# Definition of a "modular Galois representation"

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, definition, modular-forms, galois-representations

I am trying to pin down a definition for a  $n$-dimensional modular Galois representation $$\rho : \text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow \text{GL}_n(A).$$

I am just looking for the specific properties or a reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=2$, I recommend Serre's "Sur les représentations modulaires de degré 2 de $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$", Duke Math. Journal, Vol. 54, No. 1, 1987.